# Memory leaks on Gnostice PDF Toolkit

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I'm using Gnostice PDF Toolkit v5.0.0.457, and it works fine to operate with PDF files (merge files, split files, insert blank pages, insert text watermarks, insert image watermarks, print files, ...).

But I always have big memory leaks that prevent me to use it on the server side.

Am I doing something wrong in this code (it simply adds a text watermark to a PDF file) ? :

```
implementation
{$R *.dfm}

uses gtCstPDFDoc, gtPDFDoc;

procedure TTestForm.btnTestWatermarkClick(Sender: TObject);
var PDFDoc: TgtPDFDocument;
    txtWatermark: TgtTextWatermarkTemplate;
begin    
  PDFDoc := TgtPDFDocument.Create(nil);
  txtWatermark := TgtTextWatermarkTemplate.Create;
  try
    PDFDoc.LoadFromFile('C:\Temp\Test.pdf');

    txtWatermark.FontEncoding := feWinAnsiEncoding ;
    txtWatermark.Text := 'Hello World';
    txtWatermark.Font.Name := 'Arial';
    txtWatermark.Font.Size := 12;
    txtWatermark.Font.Color := clBlack;
    txtWatermark.X := 150;
    txtWatermark.Y := 150;
    txtWatermark.HorizPos := hpCustom;
    txtWatermark.VertPos := vpCustom;
    txtWatermark.Overlay := True;
    PDFDoc.InsertWatermark(txtWatermark, '1');

    PDFDoc.SaveToFile('C:\Temp\TestOutput.pdf');
  finally
    PDFDoc.Reset;
    PDFDoc.Free;
    txtWatermark.Free;
  end;
end;
```

This simple example already generates important memory leaks.

[image]

PS: I know that the best place to get support is the manufacturer itself, but my subscription ended a year ago.

Thank you

**Update:** We have re-subscribed with Gnostice, and the current version has the memory leaks solved. Thanks to all.

Comment: Look at the report that fastmm produces. Look at the call stacks corresponding to the places where the memory was allocated. Cut the program down to the minimum necessary to reproduce the leak.

Comment: Also, your `try/finally` usage is wrong. Should be like this: `acquire try dostuff finally release end`. You must acquire **immediately** before `try`. Your code does not do that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks David, I have fixed the try/finally. I will create a FastMM report and attach it, but all the leaks are reported inside the Gnostice code. This is a minimum example, you can create a blank project, add a button on the main form and drop this code to see that memory leak. My guess is either Gnostice code is unbelievably buggy or most probably I need to do some kind of cleaning before freeing their components. The problem is that I can't locate what would that cleaning be.

Comment: Are you saying that if you remove the watermark code, the leak disappears?

Comment: Most certainly a bug in the gnostice code, releated to the pdf document contents. I abandoned this component longtime ago because of similar problems and went with SynPDF :-)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, Yes, if I comment the PDFDoc.InsertWatermark(txtWatermark, '1'); line the memory leak disappears.

Comment: @whosrdaddy Thanks, I will certainly try it to see if SynPDF can do everything I need.

Comment: You should create a proper minimal reproduction (hint make a console app so that all code is contained in a single dpr file). Make it minimal (do you need all the `txtWatermark.blah := ...` lines). And then contact the developer of the code.

Comment: Have you tried a profiler like Deleaker? It can show a call stack for each leaked object.

Comment: As a workaround I would suggest to use a separate process to process pdf files :)

Comment: I have seen the memory leak report of FastMM on another application and all the leaked objects are on calls inside Gnostice code itself. I havn't been able to set up FastMM on this test project yet (I have never set it up myself), but anyway on this test project all the code is what I have shown, so the leaks are inside the Gnostice InserWatermark process. Maybe I have to somehow cleanup that watermark before freeing, but I haven't seen it on the documentation. Nice workaround, but I will first try the proposed SynPDF, and see if it can fill my needs. Thank you.

Comment: @whosrdaddy I have tried SynPDF and sadly it doesn't work for me. It's intended to create new files from scratch, I can't load an existing file to add text and images. Looks like I will need to keep searching.

Comment: Ah yes, I only create PDF's. I guess you have to talk to Gnostice support then :)

Comment: I have re-subscribed with Gnostice, and the current version has the memory leaks solved. Thanks to all.